# How do I specify what 'this' refers to?

Tags: java, this, actionlistener

I have a JFrame, one of the buttons has to pass the frame it self as a parent, i would have used the **this** keyword, but it's returning the actionlistener, instead of the JFrame. Is there a workaround or am I writing badly?

The code:

```java
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            kMeans=new KMeans(mainWindow.table, Integer.parseInt(centroids.getText()),this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your class name that contain that code?

Comment: Else you could do `JFrame that = this` and then pass `that` instead of `this`.

Comment: @11684: that would have to be a `final JFrame that = this`; while that works, it clutters your scope, and it's simpler just to do `ClassName.this`

Comment: Forgot to try that, thanks, solved everything ;)

Comment: @WChargin Of course you are right, but I remember I once couldn't get `ClassName.this` to work (probably because I messed up), so I just wanted to supply the OP with an alternative.

Comment: One of the cases when you can't use `ClassName.this` is when you have an unnamed parent class. Imagine that your code is not inside `AFrame`, but inside another unnamed parent class (just like your listener). In this case, you have to use `that` approach suggested by WChargin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround. To use the `this` keyword in reference to an outer class, you can use `ClassName.this`. For example:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public void someMethod () {
        someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                ActionListener thisListener = this; // obviously
                MyFrame outerThis = MyFrame.this; // here's the trick
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because this code:

```
new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        kMeans=new KMeans(mainWindow.table, Integer.parseInt(centroids.getText()),this);
    }
}
```

has actually created a new object.
When you use keyword `this` in a method of this `ActionListener` implementation it literally uses `this` object, which is an `ActionListener`.

If you use `this` outside the above block, it will refer to JFrame instance.

If you want to refer to `this` instance of AFrame inside ActionListener you can do `AFrame.this` as mentioned in comments. Where AFrame is the name of your frame class, not sure which name you have in your code.

Comment: What do you mean with created a new object? Also your answer has incompleted code (missing })

Comment: Iswanto, thank you for devaluing correct answer. Way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the reference of outer class to anonymous inner class. To do so you should use `OuterClassName.this`. See the example given below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class FrameExample extends JFrame
{
    private void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(FrameExample.this,"This is the message","Message",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);//Passing the reference of outer class object using FrameExample.this
            }
        });
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                FrameExample fe = new FrameExample();
                fe.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JFrameClassName.this`. So if the name of the JFrame is MainWindow, your code would be:

```
new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        kMeans=new KMeans(mainWindow.table, Integer.parseInt(centroids.getText()), MainWindow.this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the getSource() method in the ActionEvent to acces the object where the event occured.
Example : `JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();`